# Out of stock for variants ('Only 0 left in stock') in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'm not sure when this started happening but my variants are no longer showing 'out of stock' and instead show 'Only 0 left in stock'.

So customers can click the 'Add to cart' button and try to add it to cart, even though we don't have any in stock.

It used to gray out the button when it was out of stock.

My out of stock threshold is set to 0 so that's not it.

You can see the issue in action [on this page](https://vaporizersdirect.com.au/pax-3) and [this page](https://vaporizersdirect.com.au/pax-2).

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: I just noticed it's not happening on all pages... Ex. [This one](https://vaporizersdirect.com.au/arizer-solo-2) works fine?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! The PW Bulk Editor plugin was messing with it

Answer (score 0):

When you updating through csv you need to update attributes "stock_status" and "stock". 
For example you updating zero in stock then put 0 in stock column and "outofstock" in stock_status column in csv
Its working fine with me